# XSLT code to pass a value in output XML based on a condition in input XML

Tags: xslt

- Input XML:

  ```
                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
                             <DATA>
                             <RECORDS>
                             <Group>
                             <Name>12345</Name>
                             <Grp>MANAGER</Grp>
                             <FName>Alex</FName>
                             <LName>Johnson</LName>
                             <String1>abcd</String1>
                             /Group>
                             <Group>
                             <Name>67891</Name>
                             <Grp>PROJECT MANAGER</Grp>
                             <FName>JAMES</FName>
                             <LName>HARPER</LName>
                             <String1></String1>
                             </Group> </RECORDS> <LOGIN>
                             <User>
                             <Name>12345</UserName>
                             <Last>14/02/2013</Last>
                               </User>
                              <User>
                             <Name>67891</Name>
                             <Last>14/01/2013/Last>
                             </User> </LOGIN> </DATA>
  ```

  Requirement:
  In output XML

  If String1 has a value then Type tag should have value as "axbx" and
  if String1 is blank then Type tag should have value as "dydy"

  ```
                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
                            <DATA>  
                             <RECORDS>
                              <Group>
                             <Name>12345</Name>
                             <Grp>MANAGER</Grp>
                             <FName>Alex</FName>
                             <LName>Johnson</LName>
                             <Type>axbx</Type>
                             </Group>
                             <Group>
                             <Name>67891</Name>
                             <Grp>PROJECT MANAGER</Grp>
                             <FName>JAMES</FName>
                             <LName>HARPER</LName>
                             <Type>dydy</Type>
                             </Group> </RECORDS> </DATA>
  ```

  Please suggest.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't edit your question so I copy the corrected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <RECORDS>
        <Group>
            <Name>12345</Name>
            <Grp>MANAGER</Grp>
            <FName>Alex</FName>
            <LName>Johnson</LName>
            <String1>abcd</String1>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Name>67891</Name>
            <Grp>PROJECT MANAGER</Grp>
            <FName>JAMES</FName>
            <LName>HARPER</LName>
            <String1></String1>
        </Group>
    </RECORDS>
    <LOGIN>
        <User>
            <Name>12345</Name>
            <Last>14/02/2013</Last>
        </User>
        <User>
            <Name>67891</Name>
            <Last>14/01/2013</Last>
        </User>
    </LOGIN>
</DATA>
```

and the XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="String1">
        <Type>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 0">axbx</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>dydy</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Type>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not very experienced so there might be a better way.